# upload image to custom folder (fastapi)

Tags: python, fastapi, shutil

When I try to upload an image,  images uploads in the main dir. how can I change the upload destination into the media folder?

```py
@router.post('/icon', status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,)
async def create_file(single_file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    with open(single_file.filename, "wb") as buffer:
        shutil.copyfileobj(single_file.file, buffer)
    return {"filename": single_file}
```

Comment: You're not prepending the path (`single_file.filename`). If you want to store the file somewhere else, prefix the filename with the path where you want to store it. Be aware that you should usually not make uploaded files from users that you do not trust directly available somewhere in your webroot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `shutil` module, but obviously, you should use

```
with open(f'my_dir/{single_file.filename}', "wb") as buffer:
```